# How does one estimate the cost of using ActionCable on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-5

I can't seem to find any answer on this without fully understand the complexities of ActionCable and deployment with ActionCable. I'm finally switching to Rails 5 from Rails 4 and this will be my first time messing with ActionCable for a real, non-tutorial, project.

The client will surely ask what this is going to cost or how to even begin to understand what it will cost. Let's say for instance, we have 1000 users a day. Instead of polling for location of a user's iOS device every 30 seconds or so, I'd like to have the iOS client push their location to the server. I imagine it is a better practice (and possible easier now that there is ActionCable) than the old polling method.

What would be your way of going about calculating potential cost and load on the server (what Heroku dynos are needed, how many, how large of a Redis DB). Maybe it's best to estimate what is necessary per 1000 users so they can estimate cost based on their rollout goals)? Is it that simple or is it far more complex of a question to answer than I think it is?

Comment: *Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.*

Comment: Got it, thanks, Phiter.

Comment: I believe that memory requirements are higher due to Redis and that rails keeps objects while connected for each socket (subscription classes etc)